# Newly added files to document library client object model

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I am developing an application which is will be deployed in the client machine.

Client will be downloading the applications from SharePoint to local machine to a fixed folder(folder wont get changed).

Once the application is downloaded to local machine, and after some time if we updated some contents(add new files and folder) in document library is there any way to keep the both folder synchronous?

If not, is there any way to get details of Newly added files in a SharePoint document library?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but the typical way remotely distributed apps keep themselves up to date is a call back to a server, each time they initialize, to check if they are using the most up to date versions of specific resource files.

If the client detects it is out of date, it can then just ask the user if they want to update, and then your app can trigger some programatic file updates if they say yes.